# Embed logo into email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, html-email

I'm wondering how can I embed a logo into email. The logo is saved on Google Drive. Also, I know the reference inlineimage and blob need to be used but I don't know how.

I tried this code, but no success

> `var Img = DriveApp.getFileById(1pRBZ....cKMFll1OouC..er2V97e8...).getBlob();`

The line below retreive the message template. So, I want to include the image into the message as a signature.

> `var TemplateTexte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();`

```
function EnvoiIDCourriel() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Liste").activate();
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var LR = SS.getLastRow()

  var TemplateTexte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  //Permet d'utiliser le corps du courriel qui se trouve dans l'onglet Template


  //Logger.log(NomCandidat);

  //Cette ligne permet de passer à travers de toutes les lignes inscrites
  var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
    if (check === true) {
       var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
       var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage);
  }
});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add a logo image to the email using the inlineimage.
- The logo image file is put in your Google Drive.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to add the logo image to the email, it is required to use the HTML body.
- In this case, `options` of `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` is used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
  var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
    if (check === true) {
       var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
       var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage);
  }
});
```

To:

```
var fileId = "###";  // Added: Please set the file ID of the logo image.
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();  // Added
var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
  if (check === true) {
    var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
    var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    var html = CorpsMessage + '<BR><img src="cid:logo">';  // Added
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage, {htmlBody: html, inlineImages: {logo: blob}});  // Modified
  }
});
```

or

To:

As other modification, this is the method for using the HTML template. By this, you can prepare the HTML body of the email as a file.

```
var fileId = "###";  // Added: Please set the file ID of the logo image.
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();  // Added
var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
  if (check === true) {
    var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
    var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");  // Added
    html.text = CorpsMessage;  // Added
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage, {htmlBody: html.evaluate().getContent(), inlineImages: {logo: blob}});  // Added
  }
});
```

And, please create a HTML file at the script editor as the filename of `index.html` and copy&paste the following HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <?= text ?>
    <BR>
    <img src="cid:logo">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, `CorpsMessage + '<BR><img src="cid:logo">'` is used as the HTML body. So if you want to modify for your actual situation, please modify this.

  - `logo` of `cid:logo` is corresponding to `logo` of `inlineImages: {logo: blob}`.
- If the email client cannot read the HTML email, the logo is not shown. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

### Added:

- From [your replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163790/embed-logo-into-email/62164039?noredirect=1#comment109965820_62164039), you want to use the email template as follows.

  ```
  Bonjour {Nom},

  Ceci est vorte code d'identification : {ID}

  Ce code devra être utillisé lors de votre examen en Iigne pour le processus : {Processus}.

  Bon succés !

  ---
  Equipe des tests en ligne

  Service des Ressources Humaines
  ```

For this, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify above template as follows.

#### From:

```
Equipe des tests en ligne
```

#### To:

```
{LOGO}
```

In this modification, `{LOGO}` is replaced with the logo image.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
  var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
    if (check === true) {
       var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
       var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage);
  }
});
```

To:

```
var fileId = "###";  // Added: Please set the file ID of the logo image.
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();  // Added
var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
  if (check === true) {
    var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
    var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    var html = CorpsMessage.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace('{LOGO}', '<img src="cid:logo">');  // Added
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage, {htmlBody: html, inlineImages: {logo: blob}});  // Modified
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To send an image from your Google Drive in an email:
1. Make the image file as sharing to "Anyone with the link"
2. Copy the image ID from the shared link
3. In your application which is sending the email retrieve this image as a blob

```
var imageBlob = DriveApp
                  .getFileById(imageID)
                  .getBlob()
                  .setName("Logo");
```

To include the image in your email, you need to compose your email using html tags.
Declare a variable to hold the html script.

```
var html = ""
```

The above variable will be used to hold the contents of your entire email, using html tags to preserve formatting.
If html tags are not included, the email may not be displayed correctly across devices. There may be mislaignment of paragraphs, tables, images may not be displayed, etc.

```
html = '<body>' + 
html = html + '<p style="color:grey; font-family: Palatino, Times, serif; font-size: 16px;font-style: italic;">';
html = html + CorpsMessage + '</p>';
html = html + '<div align=' + imageAlignment +'><img src="cid:image" width=' + imageWidth + '%height='+ imageHeight + '% align=' + imageAlignment +'></div><br><br></body>';
```

You then send your email using GmailApp.sendEmail or MailApp.sendEmail:

```
try{
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '',{ 
  cc: emailCc,
  bcc: emailBcc,
  htmlBody: html,
  inlineImages:{image: imageBlob}});
  sheet.getRange("G28").setFontColor("#228B22");
  sheet.getRange("G28").setValue("Latest update: Mail sent @" + new Date());  
    }catch(e){
      sheet.getRange("G28").setFontColor("#FF0000")
      sheet.getRange("G28").setValue("Alert! Error: " + "  " + new Date() + "  " + e.message)
  }
```

Always enclose sendEmail method in a try/catch block, if for any reason there is an error even in 1 message, all messages following the error message will not be sent. This is irrespective of the email being in simple text format or in html format. 
Enclosing a try/catch block prevents sending only erroneous messages. Correct messages only will be sent.

Comment: Hi Sharken, You put your finger on the right spot. In fact, it's important to use the html tags to ensure that the email is readable. Where can I include the html var in my code and also, how the tags should be, by creating an html project ?
In your try method;you're referring to range G28, what does it mean ?
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi Mous, Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: 1. Where can I include the html var in my code? -  "html"  is just another declaration of a variable. I have named my variable as "html" to hold the html script. You can use any recoginised naming convention to declare and use a variable.

Comment: 2. how the tags should be?- html is used for data/information presentation only. The data/information is to be viewed on a web page using a browser like Google's Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft IE and numerous others. To bring about a certain level of standardization between these products, the majority html tags are recognised by all of them. As a starting point, a list of html tags can be found at this webpage: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_byfunc.asp

Comment: 2.  how the tags should be?(2/2) - Certain tags are not recognised in an email client and may not work. When sending html formatted emails, it is better to test your code across various devices and email clients to see if the image is displayed correctly. If your customer has installed a firewall, firewalls may prevent displaying email content. Email filters may not render html and may also mark your email as spam.

Comment: by creating an html project?(1/2) - You could create a html file in your existing project by clicking File>New>HTML file. Type out the HTML script and return it to the function from which the email is sent. But this is unnecessary from what I see in the code you have shared. The HTML script can be included inline with the apps script code in code.gs file. In this case, care must be taken to ensure the HTML script is correct. There is no way to error check the script for lapses in formatting, missing tags etc.

Comment: by creating an html project?(2/2) - Test your email multiple times by sending it to yourself and making sure all elements of your email are there.

Comment: 3. you're referring to range G28, what does it mean - "G28" is the cell address of the Google Sheet. You have used variable SS as the name of the active sheet to get the cell values. I have used the variable name "sheet" to settRange("G28")'s value depending on whether the email was sent successfully or if there was an error. If there was an error I can check for errors, if no error has occured an email was sent successfully message is displayed in cell G28 along with the time at which the email was sent.

Comment: Hi Sharken, Thnak you so much for your explanations.
BTW, I want to use this bit of code:

https://imgur.com/a/e99EKIu

This is the error message:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'catch' (ligne 34, fichier "SendIDEmail.gs")

Why this error ?

Comment: I found the error, I fotgot the tag try{. It works fine. I would like to have the value "Latest update: Mail sent" in column I every time an email is sent whatever is the row.